# Is supervisord needed for docker+gunicorn+nginx?

Tags: django, docker, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm running django with gunicorn inside docker, my entry point for docker is:

CMD ["gunicorn", "myapp.wsgi"]

Assuming there is already a process that run the docker when the system starts and restart the docker container when it stops, do I even need to use supervisord? if gunicorn will crash won't it crash the docker and then restart?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The only time you need something like supervisord (or other process supervisor) in a Docker container is if you need to start up multiple independent processes inside the container when the it starts.

For example, if you needed to start *both* nginx and gunicorn in the same container, you would need to investigate some sort of process supervisor.  However, a much more common solution would be to place these two services in two separate containers.  A tool like [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) helps manage multi-container applications.

If a container exits because the main process exits, Docker will restart that container if you configured a restart policy when you first started it (e.g., via `docker run --restart=always ...`).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no. And yes you can start both `nginx` and `gunicorn` in the same container. You can either create a script which executes everything your container needs to run and start it with `CMD` at the end of your `Dockerfile`. Or you can combine everything like so:

```
CMD (cd /usr/src/app && \
     nginx && \
     gunicorn wsgi:application --config ../configs/gunicorn.conf)
```

Hope that helps!