# Supervisor on a Digital Ocean docker image

Tags: django, docker, supervisord, cookiecutter-django

(beginner question)

I've successfully setup a nginx+gunicorn+django docker image on a Digital Ocean droplet.

My Django project follows the very good Cookie-Cutter-Django pattern ([see here](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django)).

[In this doc](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment-with-docker.html#supervisor-example), there is a description of a supervisor install.

What I'm missing here is WHERE is the supervisor supposed to be running? Local or remotely?

I understand that if I install the supervisor on my laptop it will "keep-alive" my command "docker-compose up".

But what if I take 1 week off and my laptop runs out off battery?

Will the supervisor stop its job?

If so, I need to install it on my droplet, right?

Comment: Why would it matter if your laptop runs out of battery? Are you hosting your site using your laptop or the droplet?

Comment: My site is hosted on the droplet. I don't understand where the supervisor will be running.

Answer (score 2):

Supervisor should run on your droplet. It will make sure that your webserver restarts automatically if it ever gets interrupted. An example configuration would be something like the following from [this excellent blog post](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/):

```
[program:hello]
command = /webapps/hello_django/bin/gunicorn_start                    ; Command to start app
user = hello                                                          ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /webapps/hello_django/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log   ; Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true                                                ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8                       ; Set UTF-8 as default encoding
```

Answer (score 0):

I was a bit confused.
This SO post was helpful : [Is supervisord needed for docker+gunicorn+nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722154/is-supervisord-needed-for-dockergunicornnginx)
As for this tuto: https://blog.codeship.com/ensuring-containers-are-always-running-with-dockers-restart-policy/

I've now added a "restart: always" on my compose.yml file:

```
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    restart: always
```